# How to set User read permission on FBLoginview in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios6

I use Facebook SDK and `FBLoginView` for login to Facebook and I got a basic user information , but I need more permissions like `email`,`birthday`. 
How to add permissions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
FBLoginView *loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
loginView.readPermissions = @[@"email", @"user_likes"];
```

Comment: I did this,, but in fetch data method im getting null for the email. why is that? Can you help me?

Comment: Sorry, the link you followed may be broken, or the page may have been removed.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
    - (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {

             NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"email", nil];
                 return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:permissions allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
             [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
                 }];
    }
```

Call this method with `YES` , you can give different permission like

```
[[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            @"email",
                            @"user_birthday",
                            @"user_likes",
                            @"user_location",
                            @"user_photos",
                            @"read_stream",
                            @"publish_stream",
                            @"publish_actions",
                            @"status_update",
                            @"user_about_me",
                            @"read_friendlists",
                            @"friends_about_me",
                            @"friends_birthday",
                            @"friends_photos",
                            nil] retain];
```